# gulp.spritesmith can't find retina images when in a subdirectory

Tags: gulp, css-sprites

I've been trying to get gulp.spritesmith working with retina images but with not luck.

As long as my images are at the same level as the gulp file, everything works as expected. If I move my images to a subdirectory and change the gulp.src to point to it, I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: Retina settings detected but 0 retina images were found. We have 2 normal images and expect these numbers to line up. Please double check `retinaSrcFilter`.
```

Here's the setup I've got:

```
gulp.task('sprite', function () {
  var spriteData = gulp.src('img/*.png')
  .pipe(spritesmith({
    retinaSrcFilter: '*@2x.png',
    imgName: 'spritesheet.png',
    retinaImgName: 'spritesheet@2x.png',
    cssName: 'sprites.scss'
  }));

  return spriteData.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Again, if I change the src to be

```
var spriteData = gulp.src('*.png')
```

and have the same images there, everything is fine.

Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might need the dir in the retinaSrcFilter glob too?

```
gulp.task('sprite', function () {
  var spriteData = gulp.src('img/*.png')
  .pipe(spritesmith({
    retinaSrcFilter: 'img/*@2x.png',
    imgName: 'spritesheet.png',
    retinaImgName: 'spritesheet@2x.png',
    cssName: 'sprites.scss'
  }));

  return spriteData.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. I don't know whether I'm more surprised it worked, or that I hadn't tried it. Thanks!